# Expected time to reach destination using three different routes with different probabilities

Tags: probability

What is the expected time person X reaches his destination if there are three different routes with probabilities of X taking each route A 0.2,B 0.5 and C 0.3.

If X takes route A with probability of 0.2 he travels 2 hours and finds out that the part ahead is under construction. So he has to come back to his starting point. This makes 4 hours total.

If X takes route B with probability of 0.5 he travels 1 hour and finds out that the road ahead is blocked due to protests. So he has to come back to his starting point. This makes 2 hours total.

If X takes route C with probability of 0.3 he travels 3 hours and reaches his destination.

What is the expected number of hours after which he reaches his destination.

If he takes route A or B he can again take those routes A or B with the same probability.

Comment: What is X's choice after taking route A, back at the starting point? Can it be A again?

Comment: Yes it can be A again. The process only stops if he reaches his destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider X's first choice. It is A with probability $p_A=0.2$, then X lost $H_A=4$ hours for nothing, after which X must start again as if nothing happened. It is B with probability $p_B=0.5$, then X lost $H_B=2$ hours for nothing, after which X must start again as if nothing happened. It is C with probability $p_C=0.3$, then X arrives after exactly $H_C=3$ hours. Thus the mean time $T$ to reach destination solves
$$
T=p_A\cdot(H_A+T)+p_B\cdot(H_B+T)+p_C\cdot H_C.
$$
The value of $T$ follows. Remembering that $p_A+p_B+p_C=1$, one finds
$$
T=H_C+\frac{p_A}{p_C}\cdot H_A+\frac{p_B}{p_C}\cdot H_B,
$$
which suggests another, independent, way to arrive at the result: count the mean number of times X uses each road.

This assumes that X forgets everything, the choices made previously and the status of the roads used, each time X gets back at the starting point.